# What can I do to monitor "out of shared memory" issues?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, rails

I'm new to database administration and I would really like some advice on what tools I could use or what I could do to monitor "out of shared memory" issues.

I've been seeing these "out of shared memory" messages when I've been running *rspec* which runs tests for my application. I've also seen messages in the browser when I run my rails app  that I "might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction."

I think it would be better to find out exactly what is going on first either on the driver level or the PostgreSQL level.

My specs are:

PostgreSQL 9.4.5 on x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76), 64-bit

I have a Macbook Pro running OSX El Capitan 10.11.5

I'm using the gem *pg* version 0.18.4 in my Ruby-on-Rails application.

Answer (score 1):

To monitor postgres logs you can navigate to `cd "/usr/local/var/postgres"` where you will find the `server.log` file.

If you want to watch the log in action you can pass the following command into the terminal `tail -f server.log`

Run your application in the background and if there is an issue occurring in postgres the `server.log` will catch it.

In my case, I ran RSpec in the background as that's where I saw the original "out of shared memory" message occur. The postgres log picked it up when it happen.